# Ubuntu USB install stuck after GRUB

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop from a USB. I can get to the GRUB menu, where I can select try without installing, install, etc. Upon selecting any of these options, I go directly to a black screen. Things I have tried:

Making a new USB stick (tried startup disk creator as well as unetbootin)

Using different USB all together

Editing Linux line to use nomodeset

Turned off secure boot

Editing Linux line to use nouveau.modeset=0

Using the nouveau.modeset option gave me the most success. Using this option I got to the purple Ubuntu loading screen with the 5 dots. The dots loaded and then moved on to another blank screen. Sometimes I would hear the Ubuntu theme, but the screen would stay blank. I did not have tty options or anything. I could <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>del</kbd> to restart however.

My system:

- HP Zbook 15 g4
- Intel core i7-7820HQ
- Some model of Nvidia graphics card (not remembering which at the
  moment)

If anyone has ideas I would appreciate it greatly. I honestly have no idea how to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for helping. The solution was to set `acpi=off` instead of `nomodeset`. That allowed me to install and get into 18.04.